# Mathematicians Measure Infinities, and Find They're Equal!

Tags: set-theory

I came across this article in scientific american article with the title "[Mathematicians Measure Infinities, and Find They're Equal](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-measure-infinities-find-theyre-equal-20170912)". I am quite quite baffled by this. Can someone give me some implications that this new finding might have and how it affect might affect the mathematical community ??

Comment: You have to report more detail about which infinities are equal, not just the title. It's been known for a long time that there are different infinities. Whether two particular infinities are the same or different can be an open question - perhaps one such question was settled and this article is reporting that.

Comment: @EthanBolker https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-measure-infinities-find-theyre-equal-20170912/ Have a look at it yourself

Comment: @AyanShah Users should not be expected to follow links to understand the question. Please post the related information here instead.

Comment: Thsi is not a duplicate question..

Comment: Agree, why was this marked as a duplicate? The title of the article is frustrating, because it implies a (wrong) broad result, rather than a specific result about two specific infinities...

Comment: I've cast the last reopen vote. While this question is very similar to the question ["Is there a bijection between the reals and the naturals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427404/is-there-a-bijection-between-the-reals-and-naturals?noredirect=1&lq=1), they are different questions: the latter asks about a specific interpretation of the result, while this one asks about the impact/content of that result.

Comment: It seems to me this link had not been mentioned before in this thread: https://gowers.wordpress.com/2017/09/19/two-infinities-that-are-surprisingly-equal/#more-6359

Comment: You may enjoy reading this thread: https://plus.google.com/+johncbaez999/posts/KXnZmQZmNTy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's very rough summary of the context of that article:

It's been known for a long time that there are different infinities. Two particular infinities technically known to mathematicians in this research area  as $\frak p$ and $\frak t$ were long thought to be (consistently) different, but no one could prove that.

It turns out that they are equal.

The article goes on to say

> [Malliaris and Shelah]'s work has ramifications far beyond the specific question of how
>   those two infinities are related. It opens an unexpected link between
>   the sizes of infinite sets and a parallel effort to map the complexity
>   of mathematical theories.

which begins to answer your question about

> implications that this new finding might have and how it affect might
>   affect the mathematical community.

I doubt that it will affect most of everyday advanced mathematics much, but may be very significant in particular areas of research.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Edited thanks. Not my area of expertise; I was trying to express the gist of the idea simply to answer the OP's question. But the details ought to be right.